# Refactor java code - arraylist contains with if/else

Tags: java, java-8

Is it possible to refactor below if/else part in elegant way? Please share your expertise and feedback.

```
if(onlineAreaPrioList.contains("ladies")){
            dominantOnlineArea = "ladies";
        }else if(onlineAreaPrioList.contains("kids")){
            dominantOnlineArea = "kids";
        }else if(onlineAreaPrioList.contains("men")){
            dominantOnlineArea = "men";
        }else if(onlineAreaPrioList.contains("home")){
            dominantOnlineArea = "home";
        }
```

Note: priority order = ladies > Kids > Men > Home

**Output**:
values in hashmap :{men=2, ladies=2, home=2, kids=1}

values in onlineAreaPrioList :[men, ladies, home]

**ComputedOnlineArea: ladies**

Below are the entire code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

import dto.ProductDTO;


public class Test {

    static Map<String, Integer> freq = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ProductDTO> recentlyBoughtList = recentlyBought();
        List<ProductDTO> recentlyViewedList = recentlyViewed();

        String finalOnlineArea = getDominantOnlineArea(recentlyViewedList,recentlyBoughtList);
        System.out.println("ComputedOnlineArea: "+finalOnlineArea);
    }

    private static String getDominantOnlineArea(List<ProductDTO> recentlyViewedList,List<ProductDTO> recentlyBoughtList) {

        for (ProductDTO productDTO:  recentlyViewedList) {
            countPrimaryOnlineArea(productDTO);
            addSecondaryOnlineAreaWithPrimary(productDTO);
        }

        for (ProductDTO productDTO:  recentlyBoughtList) {
            countPrimaryOnlineArea(productDTO);
            addSecondaryOnlineAreaWithPrimary(productDTO);
        }

        System.out.println("values in hashmap :"+freq);

        return getOnlineAreaBasedOnDefaultPriorityOrder();

    }

    private static String getOnlineAreaBasedOnDefaultPriorityOrder() {

        String dominantOnlineArea = null;
        Set<String> onlineAreaPrioList = new HashSet<String>();

        int maxValueInMap=(Collections.max(freq.values()));  
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : freq.entrySet()) {  
            if (entry.getValue()==maxValueInMap) {
                //System.out.println(entry.getKey());  
                onlineAreaPrioList.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }

        System.out.println("values in onlineAreaPrioList :"+onlineAreaPrioList);

        if(onlineAreaPrioList.contains("ladies")){
            dominantOnlineArea = "ladies";
        }else if(onlineAreaPrioList.contains("kids")){
            dominantOnlineArea = "kids";
        }else if(onlineAreaPrioList.contains("men")){
            dominantOnlineArea = "men";
        }else if(onlineAreaPrioList.contains("home")){
            dominantOnlineArea = "home";
        }
        return dominantOnlineArea;
    }

    private static void countPrimaryOnlineArea(ProductDTO productDTO) {
        String pOnlineArea = productDTO.getPrimaryOnlineAreaId();
        if(OnlineAreaNotEmptyAndNotNull(pOnlineArea))
            checkAndIncreaseOnlineAreaCount(pOnlineArea);
    }

    private static boolean OnlineAreaNotEmptyAndNotNull(String onLineArea) {
        boolean onlineAreaFlag = false;
        if(null!=onLineArea)
            onlineAreaFlag = true;
        return onlineAreaFlag;
    }

    private static void addSecondaryOnlineAreaWithPrimary(ProductDTO productDTO) {
        String onlineArea = productDTO.getOnlineAreaIds();
        if(OnlineAreaNotEmptyAndNotNull(onlineArea)) {
        if(onlineArea.contains("|")) {
            String[] onlineAreaSplit = onlineArea.split("\\|");
            for(String online : onlineAreaSplit) {
                checkAndIncreaseOnlineAreaCount(online);
            }

        }else {
            checkAndIncreaseOnlineAreaCount(onlineArea);
        }
        }

    }

    private static void checkAndIncreaseOnlineAreaCount(String onlineArea) {
        int count = freq.containsKey(onlineArea) ? freq.get(onlineArea) : 0;
        freq.put(onlineArea, count + 1);
    }


    private static List<ProductDTO> recentlyBought() {
        List<ProductDTO> recentlyBoughtList= new ArrayList<ProductDTO>();

        ProductDTO productDTO1 = new ProductDTO();
        productDTO1.setPrimaryOnlineAreaId("ladies");
        productDTO1.setOnlineAreaIds("ladies");

        ProductDTO productDTO2 = new ProductDTO();
        productDTO2.setPrimaryOnlineAreaId("men");
        //productDTO2.setOnlineAreaIds("men"); //comment

        recentlyBoughtList.add(productDTO1);
        recentlyBoughtList.add(productDTO2);
        return recentlyBoughtList;
    }

    private static List<ProductDTO> recentlyViewed() {
        List<ProductDTO> recentlyViewedList= new ArrayList<ProductDTO>();

        ProductDTO productDTO1 = new ProductDTO();
        productDTO1.setPrimaryOnlineAreaId("home");
        productDTO1.setOnlineAreaIds("home");

        ProductDTO productDTO2 = new ProductDTO();
        //productDTO2.setPrimaryOnlineAreaId("men"); //comment
        productDTO2.setOnlineAreaIds("men|kids");

        recentlyViewedList.add(productDTO1);
        recentlyViewedList.add(productDTO2);
        return recentlyViewedList;
    }



}

package dto;

public class ProductDTO {
    private String primaryOnlineAreaId;
    private String onlineAreaIds;
    private String ageId;

    public String getPrimaryOnlineAreaId() {
        return primaryOnlineAreaId;
    }
    public void setPrimaryOnlineAreaId(String primaryOnlineAreaId) {
        this.primaryOnlineAreaId = primaryOnlineAreaId;
    }
    public String getOnlineAreaIds() {
        return onlineAreaIds;
    }
    public void setOnlineAreaIds(String onlineAreaIds) {
        this.onlineAreaIds = onlineAreaIds;
    }
    public String getAgeId() {
        return ageId;
    }
    public void setAgeId(String ageId) {
        this.ageId = ageId;
    }


}
```

Comment: what would qualify as an "elegant way"?

Comment: I feel i done multipe if condition over there. Most of the time, i get sonar violation if i use multiple if/else statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to convert the chain of `if`s to an enhanced `for` loop:

```
for (String kind : new String[] {"ladies", "kids", "men", "home"}) {
    if (onlineAreaPrioList.contains(kind)) {
        dominantOnlineArea = kind;
        break;
    }
}
```

Consider replacing "magic strings" (i.e. `"ladies"`, `"kids"`, `"men"`, and `"home"`) with string constants defined at the appropriate level.

Another approach is to replace "magic strings" with `enum`s, which will let you switch the type of `onlineAreaPrioList` to `EnumSet`:

```
public enum PriorityKind {
    LADIES, KIDS, MEN, HOME 
}
...
EnumSet<PriorityKind> onlineAreaPrioList = new EnumSet<>();
```

Comment: Great. Thank you. I hope it will solve my problem. :) I will accept the answer soon.

Comment: How about using an enum for persons  and use a priorityqueue, where enum value is priority of each person?

Comment: Timothy and dasblinkenlight. Could you please throw code snippet if possible with enummap.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate answer and valuable response.

Answer (score 5):

Actually keeping them as `String`s is probably not a good idea since you want explicit priority of them. So probably defining an `Enum` would be better:

```
enum Priority {

    LADIES(1),
    KIDS(2),
    MEN(3),
    HOME(4);

    private final int weight;

    Priority(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
}
```

And then usage would be:

```
Stream.of(Priority.KIDS, Priority.MEN)
            .max(Comparator.comparing(Priority::getWeight))
            .orElse(null);
```

Comment: This could be further improved by making a stream from all enum values and using max() method instead of a Collector

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to use Stream API which produces a slightly more elegant solution:

```
dominantOnlineArea = Stream.of("ladies", "kids", "men", "home")
  .filter(onlineAreaPrioList::contains)
  .findFirst()
  .orElse(null); // handle the empty case as you wish
```

Comment: Thanks Pivovarit for your time to answer my queries. its based on java8 . I will use it.

Comment: @user2057006 actually Eugene's answer it the way to go.